# Associate each row of a table to a different variable

Tags: php

Actually with my code I print out all results together but the goal is to associate to a variable each row.

```
$sql = "SELECT modello FROM THING;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["modello"];   //this print all result but want to associate first result to variable $first and second to $second
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at fetch_all (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) which will do it in 1 statement.

Comment: @NigelRen yeah, thats preferable... I only provided a basic example based on his code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `echo $row["modello"];` to `$modellos[] = $row["modello"];` like so in the example below:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT modello FROM THING");
$modellos = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $modellos[] = $row["modello"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Now `$modellos` has the first in `$modellos[0]` and the second in `$modellos[1]` and the third in `$modellos[2]` etc etc to do with as you wish after the while loop. If you really really need them in `$first` and `$second`, add after the loop:

```
$first = $modellos[0];
$second = $modellos[1];
```